# Can you produce a number like 1.01010101... by just addition and subtraction?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I'm working on a program in C# where a Decimal variable can hold negative and positive values including 0 and those values can only change by addition and subtraction.

I have a conditional where if the result is false, the value of this variable is set to a specific number so the program knows to ignore it everywhere else in the program.

I am having a hard time picking this number that is unlikely to be produced by addition or subtraction and is unique enough to be used as a 'toggle' to ignore the variable or not.

So can a number like 1.01010101 be a suitable candidate?  This variable, according the business model of my program, is holding megawatt values that are only added or subtracted from and it's never going to be used to add 1.0 + 0.01 + 0.0001 +... It will just be adding a number with a max of 2 significant figures.

Comment: If you're working with floating-point numbers, consider using a NaN as indicator of wrong value.

Comment: The variable is of Decimal type, will NaN work with those?

Comment: Decimal in what language? Is it a BCD or what?

Comment: Decimal in C# environment

Comment: No, Decimals in C# don't support IEEE754 NaNs. You can then just use very large number like maximum supported by Decimal (79228162514264337593543950335). Working with that large numbers as normal values wouldn't be safe against overflows anyway, so it could be used as an indicator.

Comment: That works. If you can put your comment as an answer, I can give you credit for it

Comment: I strongly suggest you ask, in a programming forum, about what you're trying to do. Some languages already have some special values for things not set (e.g. in java, you can set the object to `null`). The general approach of using "magic values" to say "I'm not really a number" has its own set of problems; the main reason for doing so haven't applied for 20 or 30 years. And so forth. If you ask about your goal in a programming forum, you'll get sound programming advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Decimals in C# don't support NaNs, you can use very large number like maximum supported by Decimal (79228162514264337593543950335).

Working with that large numbers as normal values wouldn't be safe against overflows, so it could be used as an indicator.